# iPhone Save Movie Clip - Doesn't work on 3GS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The following code works on iPad and iPhone/iPod 4, but will not work on 3G/3GS, meaning the movie clips won't save.  The os on our test 3G/3GS devices is > 4.0.

```
-(void)processMovieClipSave:(NSConnection*)connection
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

SystemSoundID snapShot;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"tapsound" ofType:@"wav"]],&snapShot);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(snapShot);

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:moviePlayerController.contentURL];
NSString* path = nil;
NSString *paths = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
path = [paths stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/src.mp4"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:NO];

NSURL *clipURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
//NSLog(@"Save Clip URL: %@",[clipURL absoluteString]);

ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init]autorelease];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:clipURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) 
 {
     NSMutableDictionary *dict = nil;
     if (error)
     {
         dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
         [dict setObject:error forKey:@"error"];
     }

     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onMovieClipSaved:) withObject:dict waitUntilDone:NO];

     if (dict)
         [dict release];
 }];

[pool release];
```

}